# use php variable as an image src in js?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a project wherein i want to plot points on an image using js but i am using php for the image query. My question is how will i pass my php variable to my js script using the **imageObj.src**?

```
<!--call $img query to display image-->
<?php if(isset($img) && mysqli_num_rows($img)) : ?>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($img))
    {
    //the variable for the map_image_filepath stored in database
      $filepath = $row['map_image_filepath'];?>

      <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">Canvas not supported</canvas>
      <script src = "jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>

          var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var imageObj = new Image();

          window.onload = function()
          {
              context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
              draw();
          }

          function draw()
          {
              canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');                     
              ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
              ctx.fillStyle = "black";

              for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
              {
                  var x = Math.random()*400;
                  var y = Math.random()*300;
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.arc(x , y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                  ctx.fill();
                  ctx.stroke();
                  ctx.closePath();
              }
           }

           var image = '<?php echo $filepath ?>';

           imageObj.src = image;
</script>
```

Comment: Your code looks like it should work to me. Have you tried it? If so, what specifically is going wrong?

Comment: It looks good. What's the error?

Comment: Your problem is white space

Comment: Sure it should work...  Any issue ???

Comment: @Davіd no error at all. it only displays a blank canvas. not the one with the image being set on it

Comment: i used this solution and it worked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582785/9863745)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have not DOM init.

```
<script>
    var canvas = null;
    var context = null;
    var imageObj = null;

    window.onload = function(){
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        imageObj = new Image();

        var image = '<?php echo $filepath; ?>';
        imageObj.src = image;
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

        draw();
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";

        for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var x = Math.random()*400;
            var y = Math.random()*300;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x , y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The `<script>` element appears after the `id="canvas"` element in the DOM. There is no need to wait for the `load` event before searching for it.

Comment: @coudy.one you edited your post after my comment ofc it works now

Comment: @em96 Can you close this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to  add the value in a html div element and use Javascript to  bring this value using getElementByID(divID).val()

example:

```
    //html printing value as an example you can do anything else
    <div id="canvasImage"><?php echo $filepath; ?></div>

    //javascript
    <script> 
           var image = document.getElementById(canvasImage).value;
    </script>
```